# Participle phrase or conjunction

Tags: phrase-meaning

They believe that steady appreciation for nearly
a decade, coupled with higher inflation in China than in America,
has left the yuan overvalued against the dollar.

Is "coupled with.....America" a participle phrase ? If yes, what does it function as ?

or

"coupled with" = a conjunction

Comment: You are right on your assumption. ***coupled with ...America*** is a participle phrase. And here it functions like an adjective, modifying a noun, and here the noun is ***steady appreciation***

Comment: @Man_From_India Your comment sounds like an answer to me. ;-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. So be it then :) I will write it as an answer :) Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Grammar Lesson -**

> **What are participle phrase?**
>
> A participle phrase is an adjective phrase that starts with a
>   participle. Look at this example:
>
> 1. You could see the panther ***releasing*** its grip. (The text in italic is a participle phrase. The participle itself is in bold. The
>      participle phrase is describing the panther.)
>
> **Participle Phrases Can Start with Past Participles or Present Participles**
>
> 1. Present Participle - (ending *-ing*)
> 2. Past Participle - (ending *-ed, -d, -t, -en* or *-n*)
>
> **Distinguishing Participle phrases from Gerund phrases** - When participle phrase starts with "verb + ing", it's easy to get confused
>   with gerund phrases. The difference is the function they provide in a
>   sentence. A gerund phrase will always act like a noun, whereas a
>   participle phrase will always act like an adjective.
>
> For further study about participle phrase use the [link](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm)

**Coming to your question -**

Now you know what a participle phrase is, and also you know how to distinguish it from gerund phrases. So from the knowledge acquired, it's easy to answer your question.

You are right on your assumption. The phrase in your sentence - ***coupled with ....America*** - is nothing but a participle phrase. And like a participle phrase, it functions like an adjective here, modifying the noun - ***steady appreciation***.